# CodeIgniter SEO - one URL per language

Tags: php, codeigniter, localization, seo

I am building a website and I decided to use codeIgniter as framework. My site will be translated in two languages at release, maybe more after.  My website will be simple and include theses functions: create an account, log in, browse tutorial/FAQ pages.

I would like my URL to be simple and presented in each language so that it's easier on the human eyes, and for the search engine also.

**English:** 
mywebsite/signup  
**French:**  
mywebsite/inscription

With this setup, I need to setup a route for each page in my routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
// SIGN UP
$route['signup'] = 'signup_c/main/english';
$route['inscription'] = 'signup_c/main/french';
```

I'm wondering if this is a correct way to do it, since I won't have too many pages, I would need to add a route for each page/language.
Also, if I need to provide a link on each page letting user change the current language, what would be the best way? I thought of using a file that store all the URL for a specific page in each language, and show a ComboBox with link to all theses pages except the current page language.

```
$signup_url = array(
'english' => 'signup',
'french' => 'inscription'
);
```

or

```
$lang['url_form_signup']        = 'signup';
```

in a /language/[language_here]/url_lang.php
but not sure how I can iterate on all URL if I put it there

Thanks for guiding a newbie! :)

Comment: you could read http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html. And just create a general login page

Comment: It is better to have language code in URL but not to translate the action names. Eg user/signup/en and user/signup/fr is better than user/signup and user/inscription. Only use the language code to fetch correct language file and keep everything else same.

Comment: It is really better to have the language code in the URL? I want to see the pro/con of this method.  As for translating the action names, I see a pro with user understand better the URL and direct search result in search engine in the language they searched.  Please show me why you think it is better with a language code in the URL, thank you!

Comment: To clarify, my url would be:
www.website.com/signup 
www.website.com/inscription
seems shorter and better than using language code with english action?

Answer (score 0):

Using an internationalisation library is probably the best way to go. Using routing and different controller functions will become fairly unwieldy - keep the different languages separate from the logic may be easier to understand and maintain.

There are several internationalisation libraries for CodeIgniter, including:

- [CodeIgniter 2.1 internationalization i18n](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/CodeIgniter-2.1-internationalization-i18n)
- [I18N Library](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/I18N-Library)
- [i18n Multi language Library Helper](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/i18n-Multi-language-Library-Helper)
- [Multilingual CI : i18n package for CI 2.x](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Multilingual-CI-%3a-i18n-package-for-CI-2.x)

It's worth looking at the standard language [library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html) and [helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/language_helper.html) too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm not sure I want to use a big internationalization library. I have a solution that is working for now. I generate a special html select in the header of each page, and this select has link to the same page other language version.  I would post my answer but it takes 8hours with my low reputation ;)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion.

However I don't think I want to use a big internationalization library for my needs.
It will be some extra work but managing it myself is really simple and I prefer knowing my code.

Here is what I have done that is working.

**controller :**

```
public function index($lang)
{
    $changeLangLink = array(
                "english"=>"signup",
                "french"=>"inscription");
    $data['title'] =  lang("title_page_signup");
    $data['lang'] = $lang;
    $data['changeLangLink'] = $changeLangLink;

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/signup', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

**View(header) :**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title ?> </title>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="curr_lang" ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option value="<?php echo $changeLangLink['english']; if ($lang == 'english') echo "\" selected=\"selected";  ?>">English</option>
        <option value="<?php echo $changeLangLink['french'];  if ($lang == 'french')  echo "\" selected=\"selected";  ?>">Fran&ccedil;ais</option>
    </select>
```

The template header is generic to all my page and I just have to code a little array for each page